# Как сохранить аннотации и имена переменных метода при компиляции Kotlin в Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jitpack.io

Работаю над android SDK. Сервис для шаринга Jitpac при сборке компилирует мой kotlin class в java, меняя названия параметров метода и удаляя аннотации.

Например есть вот такой метод:

```
@Experimental
fun setStatusBarSettings(
    isEnableEdgeToEdgeModeOnStartup: Boolean,
    isDisableEdgeToEdgeModeOnDestroy: Boolean
) {
    this.isEnableEdgeToEdgeModeOnStartup = isEnableEdgeToEdgeModeOnStartup
    this.isDisableEdgeToEdgeModeOnDestroy = isDisableEdgeToEdgeModeOnDestroy
}
```

Код аннотации:

```
@RequiresOptIn(message = "This API is experimental. It may be changed in the future without notice.")
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS, AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
annotation class Experimental
```

На выходе получаю:

```
public final void setStatusBarSettings(boolean var1, boolean var2) {
    this.isEnableEdgeToEdgeModeOnStartup = var1;
    this.isDisableEdgeToEdgeModeOnDestroy = var2;
}
```

Как мне сохранить названия параметров и аннотацию?

Comment: Какой полный тип`@Retention`?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Я же скинул код аннотации

Comment: Я спрашиваю про полное имя включая имя package. `AnnotationRetention` нестандартная аннотация. Похоже что `Retention`  тоже не из JDK

Comment: Взял отсюда https://kotlinlang.org/docs/opt-in-requirements.html .Для обычного модуля все отлично работает. Jitpac релиз ведет себя странно

Comment: Может все-таки компиляция в байт-код, а не в Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы сохранить имена аргументов у функций, нужно передать опцию [`-java-parameters`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/compiler-reference.html#java-parameters) компилятору Kotlin. В `build.gradle` это задается в секции `kotlinOptions`:

```
android {
    ...
    kotlinOptions {
        ...
        freeCompilerArgs += '-java-parameters'
    }
}
```

Comment: Не отрабатывает

Comment: Проверял в новом java-проекте, так и в android-проекте. Я смотрел, что могу достать имена параметров у котлин-класса из java-класса с помощью рефлексии Java, например, так: `MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethods()[0].getParameters()[0].getName()`. В IDE когда смотрю байткод, там тоже видны названия параметров. А вы как проверяете?

Comment: Я провариваюсь в реализацию SDK Api класса и смотрю внутренности. Если добавить -keepattributes MethodParameters то имена методов сохраняются. Сейчас разбираюсь как сохранить аннотации

Comment: Все-таки этот вариант сработал, вы не знаете как сохранить аннотации?

Comment: Способ от @talex вам не помог? Лучше в одном вопросе формулировать 1 проблему. В текущем вопросе 2 разных проблемы. Заведите другой вопрос, чтобы вам могли помочь со второй частью вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно заменить `@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)` на `@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)`

Тогда аннотация будет доступна в рантайме.

Названия параметров это скользкая штука. Они напрямую не хранятся.